# Cannot bind a record to a Patient ID in .NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm working on a small .NET Core Web Api project
I'm using repository pattern with entityframework.
The project is working fine overall but there is something I don't understand and
I would appreciate if someone could tell me why it is not working properly.

Please look at the attached images

**In Swagger UI, I'm creating a new patient record and it is working fine**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**So far it is working fine - but when I try to bind a record in
the Recommendation Table to an already existing patient - it is not working properly.
It is just creating a new patient with null values.**

See images below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please tell me why this is happening.
I did not post the code here as it would be to much code.
On request - I will post my code

Comment: Can you share the code about  `bind a record in the Recommendation Table to an already existing patient`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the model of the recommendation class (model for your table). You need to fetch the patient first and then assign the object to the recommendation object then save the changes to the database.

Comment: Do you mean like this -
{
  "patientID": "850ADAC7-821B-4366-8597-0446C6314B42",
  "id": "9B4CC814-8B8C-414A-95C2-19567C8AF59E",
  "comment": "string",
  "imageFile": "string",
  "teethImage": "string",
  "bridge": "string",
  "missing": "string",
  }
}

Comment: You want to add a recommendation to a patient, so you start by selecting the patient then, To the list of recommendations of the patient, you add a new instance of recommendation. When you save the context, EF core will automatically bind the entities and add the foreign keys for you.

Comment: I'm very new to this - Can you please show me an example on how to WRITE the request the correct way to properly - add recomenndation to patient ?
Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).